# How to overload operator + in c++ to be able whrite c_str = "smth" + c_str;

Tags: c++, char, operator-overloading, operators, c-strings

I would like to make a CMyString class. It represents an object with contains char array. I need to overload opereators to be able to sum these objects. Here is this class

```cpp
CMyString::CMyString()
{
    i_length = 0;
    n_string = new char[1];
    n_string[0] = '\0';
}

CMyString::CMyString(const char *cChar)
{
    i_length = iSourceLength(cChar);
    n_string = new char[i_length];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < i_length; ii++)
        n_string[ii] = cChar[ii];
}
CMyString::CMyString(const CMyString &pcOther)
{
    i_length = pcOther.i_length;
    n_string = new char[i_length];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < i_length; ii++)
        n_string[ii] = pcOther.n_string[ii];
}
void CMyString::vCopyFrom(const CMyString &pcOther)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < i_length; ii++)
        n_string[ii] = pcOther.n_string[ii];
}

bool CMyString::bResize(int newSize)
{
    if (newSize <= 0)
        return false;

    delete(this->n_string);

    this->n_string = new char[newSize];
    i_length = newSize;
    return true;
}
//bool CMyString::bResize(int newSize) 

int CMyString::iSourceLength(const char *cChar)
{
    int i_source_length = 0;

    while (cChar[i_source_length] != '\0')
        i_source_length++;

    return i_source_length;
}
//int CMyString::iSourceLength(const char *cChar)

CMyString& CMyString:: operator= (const CMyString& pcOther)
{
    if (this != &pcOther)  // guard against  a = a;  
    {
        delete[] n_string;              // release old memory & then allocate new memory 
        i_length = pcOther.i_length;
        n_string = new char[i_length];
        vCopyFrom(pcOther);
    }
    return *this;                  // return a reference to itself to allow a = b = c; 
}
//CMyString& CMyString:: operator= (const CMyString& pcOther)

void  CMyString:: operator= (const char *cChar)
{
    if (i_length != 0)
        delete[] n_string;

    i_length = iSourceLength(cChar);  // count the length of init value
    n_string = new char[i_length];    // allocate storage 

    for (int ii = 0; ii < i_length; ii++) // copy init value into storage
        n_string[ii] = cChar[ii];
}
//void  CMyString:: operator= (const char *cChar)

CMyString& CMyString:: operator+ (const CMyString& pcOther)
{
    CMyString *c_res = new CMyString;

    if (i_length == 0 && pcOther.i_length == 0)
    {
        c_res->i_length = 0;
        c_res->n_string = NULL;
    }

    c_res->i_length = i_length + pcOther.i_length;
    c_res->n_string = new char[c_res->i_length];
    int ii;

    for (ii = 0; ii < i_length; ii++)
        c_res->n_string[ii] = n_string[ii];

    for (int ij = 0; ij < pcOther.i_length; ij++, ii++)
        c_res->n_string[ii] = pcOther.n_string[ij];

    return *c_res;
}
CMyString::operator char*()
{
    return n_string;
}
//CMyString& CMyString:: operator+ (const CMyString& pcOther)

CMyString::operator char*() const
{
    return n_string;
}
```

What should i do to be able to write c_str = "smth" + c_str?? Compiler underlines me this plus. No operator "+" matches this operands. Operands types are: const char[4] and CMyString?

Comment: Have you tried making an overload for those types? ie `const CMyString& operator+(const char[], const CMyString&);`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the complete error message.

Comment: compiler tells me its to match parametrs for this operator:(

Comment: you know that there is `std::string`, right? Writing your own string class is not an easy exercise, after years of c++ I still consider it a major challenge.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 thats an exercise on univercity unfortunotly:( and yes, i know

Comment: you are leaking quite some memory. Are you allowed to use smart pointers?

Comment: also you are using `delete` where it should be `delete[]`, sorry, but this is quite some code, but the interesting part is missing. Did you made an attempt at writing a `operator+(const char[], const CMyString&)` ?

Answer (score 0):

For more information you can visit this [website](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/94-overloading-operators-using-member-functions/).

```
class CMyString
{
private:
    string str;

public:
    CMyString(string _str) { str = _str; }

    friend CMyString operator+(string value, CMyString Str);
    string GetStr() {return str;};
};

CMyString operator+(string value, CMyString Str)
{
    return CMyString(value + Str.str);
}

int main()
{
    CMyString test("Test");

    test = "smth" + test;
    cout << test.GetStr();
    return 0;
}
```